# DSMTOP failed during start with insuficient privileges for SYSDBA user

Tags: db2

recently we upgraded our DB2 v10.5.8 to v11.1.4. We sucessfully upgraded all instances (check via db2 get dbm cfg) and then run command *db2updv111 -d dbname* to upgrade databases. Unfortunately it seems, that it was not fully successful. When I try to run dsmtop I see the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLu9D.jpg).

When I try to explicitly grant EXECUTE privilege to user I receive error message, that the object does not exist.

I tried to run it under user db2admin which is instance user with SYSADM role. When I create a new database I can run dsmtop successfully. This problem is related only to upgraded databases.

Is there any way how to bind some package or run anything which can fix the privileges? Something like reset the database to the default of that database version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ db2 "grant execute on function SYSPROC.ENV_GET_SYSTEM_RESOURCES() TO public"

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Thanks for an advice Paul, but the result is the same.

Comment: Did the `grant` run without error? What error message do you now get in dsmtop?

Comment: You might be best raising a case with IBM Support

Comment: There were no error when I run the GRANT command. I will contact IBM support. Thank you.